# Оптимизирует ли СУБД размещение одинаковых строк?

Tags: sql, mysql

Возникла потребность в создании БД с таблицей вида атрибут:значение.

| id:integer | attribute:string | value:string |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 213 | "material" | "wood" |
| 23 | "material" | "steel" |

Где `attribute` -- что-то вроде enum, но используется строка. `enum` не используется потому что заранее не известны атрибуты.

Возникает вопрос, СУБД догадается не множить копии строк `"material"`? В данном случае интересует поведение MySQL, информация по другим СУБД приветствуется.

Можно конечно названия атрибутов вынести в отдельную таблицу, то почему-то кажется некрасивым (дополнительный шаг поиска). Я не прав?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнительном справочнике нет ничего страшного. С другой стороны, если данных не очень много, то можно наплевать на дубликаты. Здесь важно определить баланс между целесообразностью, здравым смыслом и вечной оптимизацией.

Что же до MySQL, то тут трудно судить, я не специалист по её внутренностям, но можно предположить, что она это не делает, так как это означает, что ей самой надо создавать неявно эту дополнительную таблицу, а чтобы сделать это, надо точно обладать сведениями о том, насколько вероятна повторяемость данных, а такими сведениями она не располагает. Так что наиболее вероятный ответ: нет, она не делает никакой упаковки данных.

Comment: Данных будет много, магазин.

Comment: Тогда лучше сделайте отдельный справочник. Хотя, магазин - это ещё не факт, что данных много. Много данных - это когда хотя бы пару сотен тысяч записей в таблице.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle 7 и выше поддерживает битовые индексы. Они специально предназначены для оптимизации запросов по колонкам с небольшим количеством разных значений.

Comment: Oracle - на то и Oracle. Oracle умеет ОЧЕНЬ многое и очень крут. Битовые индексы, кстати, в одной из прошлых жизней очень спасли на очень большой таблице для поиска по текстовому полю со средней повторяемостью.